# Запуск сервиса в приложении Android

Tags: android, android-service

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: запускаю сервис в приложении, сервис работает отлично, но как только выключаю само приложение, то сервис некоторое время не реагирует, а в диспетчере написано "перезапуск" на против моего приложения. Как только "перезапустится", то снова работает.Как убрать перезапуск? Заранее спасибо.

```
startService(this, Service.class);
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код, как вы запускаете сервис и как "выключаете приложение".

Comment: Добавил код, выключаю сворачиваем приложение  и выключением из трея

Comment: А почитайте ответы в этом вопросе, может найдете  решение проблемы
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15452935/android-background-service-is-restarting-when-application-is-killed

Comment: и это https://stackoverflow.com/a/32437436/5634351

Comment: Есть два варианта: запускать сервис в отдельном процессе или стартовать при помощи `startForeground()`.